# what is the difference between those two statements for checking if there are numbers in a string?

Tags: java

I would like to find whether a string contains more than one number.
I have two different statement, the first one which I wrote myself does what I want, but the second does not work. I am trying to figure the meaning of the second statement.

There is A:

```
    private static boolean moreThan2Num(String string) {
    int numberOfNumbers = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(i))) {
            numberOfNumbers++;
            if (numberOfNumbers > 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is B:

```
    static boolean moreThan2Num(String str) {
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
        if(!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is my main:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "as3as123aaag3";
    String str2 = "qweqweqwe";
    System.out.println(String.format("more then 4 number in \"%s\" - %s", str1, moreThan2Num(str1)));
    System.out.println(String.format("more then 4 number in \"%s\" - %s", str2, moreThan2Num(str2)));
    System.out.println(String.format("more then 4 number in \"%s\" - %s", str1, moreThan2Num1(str1)));
    System.out.println(String.format("more then 4 number in \"%s\" - %s", str2, moreThan2Num1(str2)));
}
```

I thought the second one should work, but it did not.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: in fact, the second method does not test if only digits present in a string. It tests if non-digits are *not* present: `moreThan2Num("")` -> true

Answer (score 5):

In the second snippet you are returning false the first time you encounter a character that is not a digit. Therefore, you'll return `false` for any `String` that contains at least one character that is not a digit.

BTW, your first "moreThan2Num" method actually implements a logic that fits the name "atLeast2Num". If there are exactly two digits in the String, it will return true.

Comment: True. The second statement will not go through the whole string and it returns false if there is an element which is not a digit.